# count of pages for a pager

Tags: c#

I have X number of items and I want to count how many pages I'll need to page these items if I can put 5 items per page.

This is what I have:

```
int TotalPages = (int)(Math.Ceiling(TheItemCount / 5));
```

The line is underlined in red with an error that's saying there's an

> ambigious call between Math.Ceiling (double) and Math.Ceiling
>   (decimal)

I know this is supposed to be simple but I'm not getting the result I want. What do I need to change in my code to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of `TheItemCount` ?

Comment: @NicolasRepiquet: looks like it's the count of items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the compiler can't figure out which overload you want, so just force it to use the one of them:

```
int TotalPages = (int)(Math.Ceiling((double)TheItemCount / 5.0));
```

another way would be this:

```
int TotalPages = (int)(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(TheItemCount / 5)));
```

Comment: I believe you don't even have to cast TheItemCount to double if you use the literal `5.0`

Comment: Note that the second answer might not work as expected. If `TheItemCount` is an int, dividing it by 5 will result in an "integer division", and converting it to double then rounding it up do not makes much sense :) For instance 2 / 5 = 0, rounded up = 0.

Comment: @NicolasRepiquet, that is correct. Based on that statement the first example is the most accurate. Thanks for adding that!